# How to get the default error message for a field from simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm trying to display errors in the Materialize CSS way, by adding a data-error attribute to the  that contains the error message. I did that by overwriting the call to simple_form and using a Class that sets the data-error attribute of each label:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def custom_simple_form_for(object, *args, &block)
    options = args.extract_options!
    simple_form_for(object, *(args << options.merge(builder: CustomFormBuilder)), &block)
  end
end

class CustomFormBuilder < SimpleForm::FormBuilder
  def input(attribute_name, options = {}, &block)
    super(attribute_name, options.merge(label_html:{'data-error': 'error'}), &block)
  end
end
```

This works fine, but ofcourse I want the actual error message. I have tried everything, but don't understand how I can access the error message. If I try the error method, I get a formatted error that also contains the span.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered [custom wrappers](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Custom-Wrappers)? I'm happy to expand if this approach seems reasonable to you.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think I can manipulate the HTML attributes that way, right?